# C - Warning while compiling simple program

Tags: c

Im receiving warnings like this "warning: array subscript has type 'char' [-Wchar-subscripts]" in lines 11, 12 and 15. Whats wrong with my code?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
    char s[1000], i, d, a;

    printf("Enter a string: ");
    fgets(s, 1000, stdin );

    for(i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++){
        if (isalpha(s[i])){
            a++;
        }
        if (isdigit(s[i])){
            d++;
        }
    }

    printf("Number of digits: %d ... Number of letters: %d ", d, a);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `i` is of type `char`...

Comment: `i` should be `int` (same for `a` and `d`)

Comment: upvote for _actually_ reading the warnings and being concerned about them :) in your case, since your string length is > 127 you could really have a problem

Comment: tips: declare only one variable by line. you could do `for (int i...`

Comment: thanks guys, fixed :P

Comment: Not only is the *range* of the control variable `i` inadequate, but if it is (usually) `signed char` then you'll be getting *undefined behaviour* when using a negative index.